# How do I flex 1 item of a flex div all the way right when its inside another flex div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I seem to be havin some issues with the bottom portion of this blog card for my hobby website.[image]

As you can see im trying to go for the standard author name on the left side with the like symbol on the right side.

For whatever reason, I can't flex the heart all the way to the right. I made the parent container 100% width. I've tried all the align-self. But I can't seem to get it to work and have come to the pros for help.

```css
.container {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  align-items: flex-start
}

.picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25rem;
  background-image: url(./images/adventure.jpg);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.container__p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.container__header {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  align-self: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container__blogsummary {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
}


/*Problem CSS below*/

.icon-basic-heart {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.test {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='picture'></div>
  <p class='container__p'><span>Trending<span></p>
   <h1 class='container__header'>Survivng the Amazon Forest</h1>
   <i class='icon-basic-world'></i>
   <p class='container__blogsummary'>
    A matchbox, cantene of water and pocket knife. How I survived the Amazon rainforest for 3 days with just the bare necessaties and how you can too!
   </p>

         <!-- this is the problem div below -->
  <div class='test'>
   <p class='container_author'>James</p>
   <i class='icon-basic-heart'></i>
  </div>
 </div>
```

It's probably a fundamental mistake as I am learning flexbox throuh creating this on my own. Or maybe I havent had enough coffe today. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.test` CSS to this:

```
.test {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    // Add the following
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.icon-basic-heart {
    float: left;
}

.container_author {
    float: right;
}

.test {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

You overcomplicate things. There is no need in flex for only 2 objects - flex doesnt fit in here.

Comment: Your right, im not sure why I'm doing this to myself sometimes